# node.js modules - EventEmitter

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I'm trying to create my own module for the GPIO-Pins of a Raspberry Pi but I want to receive `.on('something', function() {  })` events, if something changed (like a button is pressed/released).

The python script sends every 0.01 Seconds a value like true or false.

module.js

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

module.exports = {
     switch_live: function(pin) {

         var status = false;

         this.get = (function(){
             return status;
         });

         var options = {
             mode: 'text',
             args: [pin],
             pythonOptions: ['-u']
         };

         var pyshell = new PythonShell('./data/switch_loop.py', options);

         pyshell.on('message', function(message) {

             if (message == 'false') {

                 if (status) {
                     // EMIT: button released

                 }

                 status = false;
             } else {

                 if (!status) {
                     // EMIT: button pressed

                 }

                 status = true;
             }



         });

         return this.status;       

    },
    some_other_funcs: function(pin) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

app.js

```
var module = require('./module.js');

var button = new module.switch_live(10);
```

The module can show you the status of the button:

```
// get status of button
var status = button.get(); // returns "true" or "false"
```

But I want something like this:

```
button.on('pressed', function() {
    // call this function every time when button is pressed
});

button.on('released', function() {
    // call this function every time when button is released
});
```

Thank you :)

EDIT: I didn't find a solution, because I need the functions inside the "module.exports".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## My Solution

It is a module for a Linkerkit-Board.

app.js

```
var linkerkit = require('./linkerkit.js');

var button = new linkerkit.switch_live(20);

button.on('pressed', function() {
  // call this function every time when button is pressed

    console.log('press');

});

button.on('released', function() {
  // call this function every time when button is released

    console.log('release');

});
```

linkerkit.js

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
var EventEmitter = require('events');
var util = require('util');

var linkerkit = {

    switch_live: function(pin) {

        var self = this;

        this.status = false;
        this.pin = pin;
        EventEmitter.call(this);

        this.get = function() {
            return this.status;
        }

        this._pyshell = new PythonShell('./data/switch_loop.py', {
            mode: 'text', 
            args: [this.pin], 
            pythonOptions: ['-u']
        });

        this._pyshell.on("message", function(message) {

            if (message === "false") {
                if (this.status === true) {
                    // EMIT: button released
                    self.emit("released");
                }
                this.status = false;
            }
            else {
                if (this.status === false) {
                    // EMIT: button pressed
                    self.emit("pressed");
                }
                this.status = true;
            }

        });

    }

}


for (var key in linkerkit) {
    util.inherits(linkerkit[key], EventEmitter);
}

module.exports = linkerkit;
```

I edited the code because it should be able to do things like that:

```
var button = linkerkit.switch(20);
button.get() // get status of button once, has no python loop

var button_live = linkerkit.switch_live(20);
button.get() // get status of button once, has a python loop
button.on('pressed', callback);
button.on('released', callback);

var led = linkerkit.led(10);
led.on();
led.off();
led.brightness(255); // digitalOutput - brightness
led.blink(200); // 100ms on, 100ms off

var ledcolor = linkerkit.led_rgb(12);
ledcolor.on(); // on -> color: white
ledcolor.off(); 
ledcolor.rgb([255, 0, 0]); // on -> color: red
```

And many more functions...

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use Node's built-in `EventEmitter` class to create your own "button emitter":

**module.js**

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

var util = require('util');
var EventEmitter = require('events');

function ButtonEmitter(pinNumber) {
  this.status = false;
  this.pinNumber = pinNumber;
  EventEmitter.call(this);
}

util.inherits(ButtonEmitter, EventEmitter);

ButtonEmitter.prototype.get = function() {
  return this.status;
};

ButtonEmitter.prototype.switch_live = function() {
  var options = {
    mode: 'text',
    args: [this.pinNumber],
    pythonOptions: ['-u']
  };

  this._pyshell = new PythonShell('./data/switch_loop.py', options);

  this._pyshell.on("message", this._handleMessage.bind(this));

  return this.status;
};

ButtonEmitter.prototype._handleMessage = function(message) {
  if (message === "false") {
    if (this.status === true) {
      // EMIT: button released
      this.emit("pressed");
    }
    this.status = false;
  } else {
    if (this.status === false) {
     // EMIT: button pressed
     this.emit("released");
    }
    this.status = true;
  }
};

module.exports = ButtonEmitter;
```

**app.js**

```
var ButtonTrigger = require('./module.js');

var button = new ButtonTrigger(10);

button.on('pressed', function() {
  // call this function every time when button is pressed
});

button.on('released', function() {
  // call this function every time when button is released
});

button.swith_live();
```

---

**Explanation**

The above code leverages Node's `util.inherits` to "subclass" `EventEmitter`, so that anyone using your class has access to `.on()`, `.off()` and other event methods. (Note: you could use ES6 `class` and `extends` syntax too, if you're Node version supports it)

Then, using your "subclass", you add your own `switch_live` method that starts the "listening" process, passing it the `_handleMessage` callback.

When the `_handleMessage` callback runs, it will compare the current status to the incoming one, and trigger a `.emit()` using the event names you posted in your question. Again, the `.emit()` is available because you a "subclassing" `EventEmitter`.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me :)

Comment: I wrote another answer to share my solution. I voted your answer up :)